# Find element dynamically on dashboard

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, jestjs, nightmare

I'm looking for a solution or at least a direction on how to find dynamically elements on a dashboard and then update what's inside into a Hashmap.
I write in javascript - jest - nightmare.
As of today, I actually updated all the elements within a map and then ran in a (forEach) loop and searched them on the screen using the existing method.
As I mentioned I'm looking for a more efficient way like running on screen and looking for element then i want to insert them into a Hashmap.
here is example as i'm doing today:

```
describe('Elements visibility', () => {
    let visibleSelector = {
        'username': '[name = "username"]',
        'password': '[name = "password"]',
        'forgotPassword': 'a[href="div.forgotPassword"]',
        'signUp': 'a[href="div.newUserText"]'
    };

    let selectorInputs = Object.keys(visibleSelector);
    selectorInputs.forEach(selector =>{
        it(format('Elements visibility: %s',selector), (done) => {
            nightmare.exists( visibleSelector[selector]).then(function (elementExists) {
               if (elementExists){
                console.log('Element exists on page');
               }
               else {
                   console.log('Element doesnt exists on page')
               }

            });
            done();
        });

    });

});
```

After searching  I found a method document.queryselectAll  that handles the issue of finding elements on page.
Anyway after more then a few attempts I have not yet been able to get what I wanted. when I print to console.log(document) I get document is undefined.
I guess it has to do with nightmar.js electron.
I would be happy with someone who can help me with this issue. I attach the new code i wrote:

```
describe('overviews',  () => {

beforeEach(  (done) => {
    nightmare.goto('https://dashboard-staging.pixoneye.com/#/login');
    nightmare.exists('[text="See the Full Picture"]');
    nightmare.url().then(url => {
        expect(url).toEqual('https://dashboard-staging.pixoneye.com/#/login');
        done();
    });
});

afterAll((done) =>{
    nightmare.end();
    done();
});
describe('test', function() {

    console.log(document);
    let pageElements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.loginForm'));
    for (let i = 0; i < pageElements.length; i++) {
        it('should ', (done) => {
            let elementInputs = pageElements[i];
            nightmare.exists(elementInputs);
            console.log(elementInputs);
            done();

        });
    }

});
});
```